# Sending email using Swift mailer in Yii2 sent wrong email contents

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer, outlook-2010, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Swift mailer to send email from my Yii2 based web applications. But it can't read/receive in MS Outlook correctly.

Please see the email body bellow which I received using MS Outlook 2010 -

```
--_=_swift_v4_1430198154_31f7ff2886dc0fb65796db153d9434096acbae54_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Dear Admin,=20
User John has been si= gned up
successfully.

Thanks,
The App Tea=
m

This message was sent to john@example.com. If y= ou don't want
to receive future emails from ABC, please unsubs= cribe.


--_=_swift_v4_1430198154_31f7ff2886dc0fb65796db153d9434096acbae54_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.=
org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org=
/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" con= tent=3D"text/html;
charset=3DUTF-8" />
<title></title>
<=
/head>
<body>
    Dear Admin, <br>
<p>User John has been signed up successfully.</p>

<=
p>Thanks,</p>
<p>The ABC Team</p>

<br><br><br> =

=09
<p style=3D'color: #B6B6B6'>
    This message was sent to =
john@example.com. If you don't want to receive future emai= ls
from ABC, please <a href=3D'#'>unsubscribe</a>.
</p> =



</body>
</html>


--_=_swift_v4_1430198154_31f7ff2886dc0fb65796db153d9434096acbae54_=_--
```

I am using following configuration for encoding-

```
 'messageConfig' => [
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
],
```

And sending using -

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('mailview', ['name' => $name]) 
            ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] => \Yii::$app->name . ' App'])
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->send();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: at what circumstance the issue arise?

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it sends email in correct readable format but sometimes it sends like what mentioned in the question.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, whereby generated email contains lot of extra '=' and '3D' characters at arbitrary positions. Any insight or reason found?

Comment: Hey, i am facing similar problem,what solution about it!

Answer (score 0):

for me help only setHtmlBoby() method, 
because example from documentation sends 3 headers with repeating content:

1. Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2. Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
3. Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Below code example:

```
//render view content
$htmlMailContent = $this->renderPartial('@common/mail/passwordCreateToken-html', ['user' => $model]);
//render layout
$htmlMail = $this->renderPartial('@common/mail/layouts/html', ['content' => $htmlMailContent]);

$mailResult = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name . ' robot'])
    ->setTo($model->email)
    ->setSubject('Password reset for ' . Yii::$app->name)
    ->setHtmlBody($htmlMail) //set here mail with layout
    ->send();
```

Comment: see method `compose()` on https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/mail/BaseMailer.php